Swagger version change breaks my Typescript model files
In a project I am currently working on there used to be a swagger.json file version 2. and now they changed to swagger 3.0.2
This is the prev. command to generate the types from swagger.json
swagger-codegen generate -i ./src/api/swagger.json -l typescript-axios -o ../swagger

and it generated files like this
/**
 *
 * @export
 * @interface Order
 */
export interface Order {
  /**
   *
   * @type {Array&lt;OrderStatusChange&gt;}
   * @memberof Order
   */
  statusHistory: any;
  /**
   *
   * @type {number}
   * @memberof Order
   */
  basketTotalInclTax: any;
  ...}

but now when use this same command it generated weird files with weird names like this
export interface ClassApiWebViewsOrderOrder_ {

    /**
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof ClassApiWebViewsOrderOrder_
     */
    id: string;

    /**
     * @type {ClassApiWebViewsOrderOrderPartnerBrief_}
     * @memberof ClassApiWebViewsOrderOrder_
     */
    partner: ClassApiWebViewsOrderOrderPartnerBrief_;

    /**
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof ClassApiWebViewsOrderOrder_
     */
    number: string;

The export name is corrupted, how do I fix this so it won't break my app ( react-native )
thanks.
I tried to migrate the generated swagger.json version 3 to version 2 but I could't find a way.
What I am expecting is to have proper names like before from version 2

What API DOC is used on the backend?

You can use this tool to convert 3.0 to 2.0 online. Or use api-spec-converter to do it.

Getting this error when trying to use it Error: Unknow format swagger_3, you might have forgotten installing an optional dependency

@SDB how to use it?
